# unable to boot or login after successful installation of Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, boot, uefi, login, ubuntu-gnome

I installed UbuntuGNOME 16.04 (64 bit) using a live USB (FAT32 formatted) in UEFI mode. The installation was successful. At the end it asked to `reboot` to use the installed system. After pressing `reboot`, the system just throws a blank grey screen and there is no place to enter login details. I could not even switch to terminal mode to see what went wrong. Any suggestions to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem was due to the fact that I was using nouveau drivers instead of *Nvidia drivers* (as of this writing, using the latest version of Nvidia 384.x solves the issue).